# Apache Spark Dataframe Groupby agg() for multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` with 3 columns i.e. `Id, First Name, Last Name`

I want to apply `GroupBy` on the basis of `Id` and want to collect `First Name, Last Name` column as list.

Example :- I have a DF like this

```
+---+-------+--------+
|id |fName  |lName   |
+---+-------+--------+
|1  |Akash  |Sethi   |
|2  |Kunal  |Kapoor  |
|3  |Rishabh|Verma   |
|2  |Sonu   |Mehrotra|
+---+-------+--------+
```

and I want my output like this

```
+---+-------+--------+--------------------+
|id |fname           |lName               |
+---+-------+--------+--------------------+
|1  |[Akash]         |[Sethi]             |
|2  |[Kunal, Sonu]   |[Kapoor, Mehrotra]  |
|3  |[Rishabh]       |[Verma]             |
+---+-------+--------+--------------------+
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can aggregate multiple columns like this:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("fName"), collect_list("lName"))
```

It will give you the expected result.

Comment: thanks man, easy and clean, still saving tone of hours doing this manually in python (in my case)

Comment: I'm glad that you found this answer helpful!.