# How to aggregate values in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val trans = df.groupBy("userId").agg(collect_list("movieId") as "features")
```

How do I aggregate other columns in the dataFrame as well? For now It is only aggregating column MovieID.

Comment: Please add some example of input/output to make it clear.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850554/apache-spark-dataframe-groupby-agg-for-multiple-columns/42850745 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Spark Dataframe Groupby agg() for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850554/apache-spark-dataframe-groupby-agg-for-multiple-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can add other aggregation  like below example

```
val trans = df.groupBy("userId").agg(collect_list("movieId") as "features",avg("rating") as "avg_rating"))
```